# parallel matrix inversion in c or c++

Tags: c++, c, mpi

Hi I know a matrix inversion operation is very expensive but for my situation i need the inverse for multiple other operations, does any one have an example of a parallel matrix inversion they can share with me?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: petsc and failed, also scalapack and failed there are no good examples on the web that i can find

Comment: If you're telling us that PETSc and Scalapack failed, you should probably say what went wrong. Those are pretty much the standard tools for this sort of requirement.

Comment: it's more a matter of me failing with them because the documentation isn't the best for them, the problem with PETSC is with not having a inverse function i was told"inversion is too expensive don't do it" and with Scalapack it's very difficult to find good documentation/examples calling it from C or C++

Comment: I figured out to get Petsc to work if any one would like to see

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Eigen library, it uses many optimizations, including Intel SSE.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page